# Why is there no Tor Bundle 3.5 for OS X 64bit?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, mac

I have 2.3.x for OS X 64 bit and recently got a notice to upgrade to 3.5, the only options were Windows and OS X in 32 bit and Linux 32 or 64.  What happened to the 64 bit version of Tor for OS X?  Is it still under development?  How do I get a notice about it added to the download page?

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is no 64-bit Tor Browser Bundle for OS X. However, the 32-bit version should work fine on 64-bit Intel CPUs and performance should be equivalent to a 64-bit version.

A 64-bit bit version is planned, but there isn't yet a timescale. See the [message below from Roger Dingledine on tor-talk](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-talk/2013-December/031470.html):

> > Also, I know that for some reason, with the latest version 3.5, the OS X
> >     build is only 32-bit. Yes, I know that Erinn has said that they will
> >     eventually get around to making 64-bit OS X builds again, but why has this
> >     happened in the first place? What broke, or is OS X simply being
> >     intentionally neglected?
>
> "intentionally neglected" is a bit strong. We have not enough packaging
>   people, not enough developers, and way too much to do. If 32-bit works
>   adequately for now I totally understand triaging that and moving on for
>   the release. The main race was to get something out with Firefox 24,
>   since Firefox 17 is no longer supported.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm not complaining about the lack of a 64 bit version so much as for the lack of any explanation.  I don't generally expect to be told to upgrade only to find that the 64 bit version of software has gone away.  It was sort of baffling and there was no documentation or notes on the Tor download page.  Seems as simple as saying "due to lack of developer time, OS X 64bit version is not yet available, please upgrade to the latest OS X 32 bit version for the time being" - probably followed by a link to where to volunteer as a developer.  I couldn't find a place to even post a comment.